# Design UI programmatically

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I'm trying desperately to design my UI programmatically.
But I think I'm in trouble to understand the concept.
Basically I want a UI which contains different UIViews and a UITableView.

But now I'm stuck with the UITableView.

So my "main view" which should contain all these views is called AddListViewController(it inherence from UIViewController).

In the loadView method of this class I'm trying to add a table, but no chance. Has anyone a good example for me. I'm really dont see the point for a separate UITableView and UITableViewController.

Comment: You mean "create the UI", not "design the UI", surely....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new UITableView, very simply like this:

```
UITableView * tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
[tableView release];
```

EDIT: The above answer beat me to it.

Comment: Barely, but I left the data source and delegate out :)

Answer (score 2):

Just create your UITableView and add it as subview:

```
UITableView *table = 
  [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
                       style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

...

[self.view addSubview: table];
[table release];
```

Answer (score 1):

In loadView, you have to make every view - including the overall view associated with the view controller.

You perhaps want to do what you are trying to do in viewDidLoad instead?

Answer (score 0):

i many be late in answering but still i am answering it
use:

```
shareListView.delegate = self;
shareListView.dataSource = self;
```